# htaccess rules to block all but server

Tags: .htaccess

looking for some htaccess rewrite rules to block all access to a directory except for the server itself.  It's a directory full of images and flash swf files.  Yes I know it's sort of odd to not want direct access to a file its own directory, but to allow it to be seen by the user when referenced in other html outside the protected directory, but thats what i'm after.  I have tried a few different methods as shown below:

```
# send them to index.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../User/ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [R=301,L,NC]

# no one gets in here!
#deny from all

Options All -Indexes

<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.0/33
</Limit>
```

None of them seem to really do what I want.  some of them block access to everything, including the server itself.  Other redirect the request to another page, but because it keeps the same url, the links on the 'page' the user gets redirected to wont work.

If possible I would not even like to do a 404 warning, because while this disallows users access to the directory, the user will still know that that directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this one line rule to do that:

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/ - [L,R=404,NC]
```

That way all the files under `/mydir/` will generate 404 errors to your visitors but your server will still have access to those files.

Comment: This rule will go into .htaccess file directly under `public_html`

Comment: Perfect. You know, it always bothers me when questioners don't show the courtesy of approving/voting on answers. You replied six minutes after the question was asked. Six years later, it's still useful.

Comment: Thanks @AlanM, OP disappeared from site after getting the answer :)